# Windows 8 search with result context

Tags: windows-8, search, windows-search, desktop-search

Is there a way to search for PDF and Word documents in Windows 8 so that the search results display not only the file name, but also some context of where the search terms occur? A sentence around the search terms would be great, or even some custom snippet size. If this is not possible using built-in Windows search, are there third-party applications, ideally free ones? Google Desktop used to do this, but it's no longer supported.

Comment: Most 3rd party search tools should do this. Have a look here for some suggestions: http://superuser.com/questions/135423/whats-a-good-alternative-to-windows-search-for-files-and-folders

Answer (score 0):

A tool such as [grepWin](http://tools.tortoisesvn.net/grepWin.html) would give you the ability to search within the files, and will give you a short snippet of the area in which the search term appears in the file.

Another tool that can accomplish this is the similarly named [Windows Grep](http://www.wingrep.com/).